# Ui mask partial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Hi for the UI mask in angularui is there a way to only grab a portion of the value from the input box?  For example:

```
 <input type="text" name="myInput" ui-mask="999-999-9999"  placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"class="form-control" data-ng-model="search.phone"   maxlength="12" ui-mask-use-viewvalue="true">
```

When I type 7783777826 it becomes 778-377-7826 (as specified by the ui-mask syntax).

However when I type 778377782 or 778377 the value is null.  I want it so that even if a user types these short values I can at least capture them .

Is it possible to grab these partial values via $viewValue?

Comment: better if you can post a jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 3):

In the uiMask module, I ended up commenting out these lines from the blurHandler function, which allows partial values to be entered without them getting set to null if invalid.

```
function blurHandler(){
  oldCaretPosition = 0;
  oldSelectionLength = 0;
   //if (!isValid || value.length === 0) {
   //  valueMasked = '';
   //  iElement.val('');
   //  scope.$apply(function (){
   //    controller.$setViewValue('');
   //  });
   //}
}
```

I realize editing the library isn't the best option, but it may be what you were looking for.